# Using SpellCheck in Multiple spellBoxes

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I want to use this regex which changes all of the spellBoxes `spellBoxes`which are imported from the WCF toolbox. The method changes the user input into to Title case, so the beginning of every word is a capital letter. I want this to used on all of my spell textboxes on my win from however rather than retyping the same function in every text box what would be the best way to use this in my WinForms project to make it more efficient and not have to use it on all of my text boxes, which is like 15.

Because I have also used a WCF Spell box and integrated into my WinForms project, I am also not able to use the `.Select` on my spellBox does not work as I expected as It was created first on a WPF textBox. So how would I be able to use this function on an on multiple `SpellBoxes` and how to use the `.select` a method as I would on the WPF `TextBox`

```
string myText = txt_HouseName.Text;
var regex = new Regex(@"[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]");// regex to change user input into Title Case.

if (myText.Equals("") || (regex.IsMatch(myText.ToString()))) // validate that the input is not a char or or null
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid value, no special chars or leaving this blank!!!!");
}

else
{
   txt_HouseName.Text = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInf‌‌o.ToTitleCase(txt_HouseName.Text.ToLow‌er());
                txt_HouseName.Focus();
                txt_HouseName.Select(txt_HouseName.Text.Length, 0);

                //Move Cursor to location of where error
}
```

Comment: Why would you need to repeat the code for all textboxes? Just create a method that receives the textbox as a parameter.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes that what i thought, I am new to winforms sorrry. Should i just create a varible inside the method say  'myText  = param.Text' ? just not to sure how to link all of the the spellBoxes? and also i cannot use the select method with the spelBox. Thanks

Comment: If you are new to Windows Forms, make sure you read on validation and Windows Forms in general *first*. This will save a lot of effort re-implementing what is already there.